# Selenium GRID2 + yml config file + multiple remote controls

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

With Selenium GRID2, how do you set up multiple remote controls?
There are 2 machines (let's call them "machine01" and "machine02") we can use, with installed browsers (some of which are installed at a specific location) on them. We want these 2 to register to the GRID2 HUB to run test cases.

I have a 3rd machine which needs to act as HUB, I start it with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub -grid1Yml grid_configuration.yml
```

But how do I set the different remote control in the yml configuration file?
During investigation on my local computer, I used this config:

```
hub:
port: 4444
remoteControlPollingIntervalInSeconds: 180
sessionMaxIdleTimeInSeconds: 300
environments:
   - name:    "Firefox 6.0 on Windows"
     browser: "*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 6.0\\firefox.exe"
   - name:    "Firefox 7.0 on Windows"
     browser: "*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 7.0\\firefox.exe"
   - name:    "Internet Explorer 8"
     browser: "*iehta"
   - name:    "Google Chrome on Windows"
     browser: "*googlechrome"
   - name:    "Safari 5.1 on Windows"
     browser: "*safariproxy C:\\Program Files\\Safari\\Safari.exe"
```

On Remote Controls I run this command:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role rc -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser "browserName=Firefox 6.0 on Windows,maxInstances=1" -browser "browserName=Firefox 7.0 on Windows,maxInstances=1" -browser browserName="Internet Explorer 8,maxInstances=1" -browser browserName="Google Chrome on Windows,maxInstances=1" -browser browserName="Safari 5.1 on Windows,maxInstances=1"`

Now that I have multiple machines available as remote control, how do I specify each machine available and where the browsers are for each machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Setting different remote controls is not through yml file. YML is used by hub. The path you specified for the browser in YML file will be used across all RC machines. So if you specify C:/programfiles/firefox/firefox.exe for firefox browser in grid_cofig.yml file, firefox should be in this path for all RC machines.
2. To register RCs from multiple machines you need to run the RC command in both machines. You should change the -hub value from localhost to the actual IP address of the hub.